# Entity Framework - Working with Detached entities issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Ok, so in this example I have a parent entity called Template. A Template always has a type. The type is an FK that is very likely to already exist. The problem comes when creating a new Template and adding to it the type. Once the type is added and you go to add the Template you receive an error. Which error you receive depends on the approach. Does anyone know how to work with this kind of situation?

```
public static void AddTemplate(Template template)
    {
        using (TheEntities context = new TheEntities())
        {
            //if (template.TemplateType.EntityKey != null)
            //{
            //    context.Attach(template.TemplateType);
            //}

            context.AddToTemplates(template);
            context.SaveChanges();

            context.RemoveTracking(template);
        }
    }
```

I have tried both attempting to attach the existing key and not. The call at the bottom to RemoveTracking is simply an extension to call detach on template and any sub entities that may have been loaded.

Here is the unit test.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void CanAddAndDeleteATemplate()
    {
        Template template = new Template();
        template.Name = "Test";
        template.Description = "Test";

        TemplateType type = TemplateManager.FindTemplateTypeByName("Round");

        if (type == null)
        {
            type = new TemplateType();
            type.Name = "Round";
        }

        template.TemplateType = type;

        TemplateManager.AddTemplate(template);

        template = TemplateManager.FindTemplateByID(template.TemplateID);

        Assert.IsNotNull(template);

        TemplateManager.DeleteTemplate(template);

        template = TemplateManager.FindTemplateByID(template.TemplateID);

        Assert.IsNull(template);
    }
```

The unit test works perfectly assuming a Template Type of "Round" does not exist yet. I am starting to wonder if this kind of stuff is possible in a detached environment.

UPDATE

Ok I changed my code for AddTemplate to this and now it works..

```
public static void AddTemplate(Template template)
    {
        using (TheEntities context = new TheEntities())
        {
            if (template.TemplateType.EntityKey != null)
            {
                TemplateType type = template.TemplateType;
                template.TemplateType = null;
                context.AttachTo("TemplateTypes", type);
                template.TemplateType = type;
            }


            context.AddToTemplates(template);
            context.SaveChanges();

            context.RemoveTracking(template);
        }
    }
```

So for all existing child entities that are added to a new parent by a client will have to have this kind of work done on them when they are ready to be persisted. Is there a cleaner way to do this? Maybe something a bit more generic?

Comment: The code you use to create the Template object would help, also the errors you're getting.  I don't think that there's anything wrong with what you've got, so the error must be outside the code you've posted.

Comment: The code to create the template is in the unit test code toward the bottom. The class information is unchanged from the EF generation.

Comment: You will notice that there is a bit of code commented out. When ran with the code commented out the error will state:
The object cannot be added to the ObjectStateManager because it already has an EntityKey. Use ObjectContext.Attach to attach an object that has an existing key..

Comment: If you uncomment the code and attach the entity it wants attached you get this:
An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The existing object is in the Unchanged state. An object can only be added to the ObjectStateManager again if it is in the added state..

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner.  The problem makes much more sense now.  Can you post the code that you use to FindTemplateByID?

Comment: The code never makes it that far. Once it tries to call context.AddToTemplates(template); in the AddTemplate method it will error.

Comment: Take a look at the update. I found a resolution but its very specific to each AddEntity type call I will write.. wish there was a more elegant way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the code to this allows for the object state manager to track the change and allow for the Template to be added.

```
public static void AddTemplate(Template template)
    {
        using (TheEntities context = new TheEntities())
        {
            if (template.TemplateType.EntityKey != null)
            {
                TemplateType type = template.TemplateType;
                template.TemplateType = null;
                context.AttachTo("TemplateTypes", type);
                template.TemplateType = type;
            }


            context.AddToTemplates(template);
            context.SaveChanges();

            context.RemoveTracking(template);
        }
    }
```